# Address picker field won't fill column 100%

Tags: forms, css

For some reason, the address picker field won't fill the width 100% like the other fields, even though I've applied the same styling:

http://realendeavors.com/dmv-form/thank-you2.htm

Is there some other css controlling the width of the address field?

Comment: I don't see any problem - it looks good. Where's the problem exactly ?

Comment: The address field is shorter than the other two fields. It only fills about 85% of the column, whereas the other two fill 100%. When resizing the browser window, the address field stays the same, but the other two widths adjust with the browser size.

Answer (score 0):

**Add the below CSS code**

```
span.twitter-typeahead {
  border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
  width: 100%;
}
span.twitter-typeahead input {
  border: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add width:100%; to the span of the input field like this.

```
<span class="twitter-typeahead" style="position: relative; display: inline-block; direction: ltr; width:100%;">
```

Comment: You're welcome. If it solved your issue, then you can mark the answer as Approved and Useful.